What does it mean to have a 500 response code with the response detail stream_idle_timeout
I am maintaining multiple connections to my websocket server through envoy and I notice 500 errors.
The response detail for some of the 500 errors were ext_Auth_error and others is stream_idle_timeout.
The connections can not timeout as I pass messages within the defined idle timeout duration. Is there an explanation on why this is happening?
Furthermore, does the external auth service deny connections when there is a high load? Any default rate limiting factor?
Checked documentation and could not find specific answers for this

500 is an HTTP server error, look at the error logs to see what makes it crash. Because nginx and envoy are both servers, check which one is creating the 500 response or if it is just passing it through

@sleepyhead
The 500 error is returned from the envoy.
Stream-idle-timeout - if the connection is idle for 300s, envoy will terminate the connection. But my issue is, this should not be happening as my connection is not idle for 300s.
ext_auth_error - this is returned from the external auth service when they cannot complete a connection. But this was observable only when large number of connections were tried to be created at once..

Rate limiting on internet facing interfaces is a common protection mechanism. But you didn't specify which Auth provider you use. Sounds like you authenticate each request externally. Good practice is to obtain a token with limited duration and use it for requests in a session a short period
